# How to copy a picture from one comment to another?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a comment on a cell that conatains a picture setted with
ActiveCell.Comment.Shape.UserPiсture "C:\path\img.png"

But I want it to be copied to another cell. How do I do that?

Comment: Use: ActiveCell.Copy anotherCell. Where 'anotherCell' must be a valid range reference to some "destination" cell

Comment: `ActiveCell.Copy anotherCell` will copy more than just the comment. You'd need to use `ActiveCell.Copy : anotherCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteComments` but even then, you're copying the entire comment, including the formats *and* the comment text.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Shape's `Pickup` and `Apply` methods, but you will get all of the set formats on the comment's shape, not just the picture.

```
Sub test()

  Dim comment1 As Shape
  Dim comment2 As Shape

  Set comment1 = Sheet1.Shapes("Comment 1")
  Set comment2 = Sheet1.Shapes("Comment 2")

  'Copy all of the formats from the comment's shape
  comment1.PickUp

  'Paste all of the copied formats to the target
  comment2.Apply

End Sub
```